# The counterpart to "overheard" when reading?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the counterpart to *overheard*, when I did not heard, but read something in passing? *Overread* is rather the opposite, namely

> To read over, or peruse.

Possible alternatives I could think of are *notice* and *found*.

From: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Overread

Comment: I don't believe there is a single word for this (that means almost nothing). The usual phrase is 'read over your/someone's shoulder'.

Answer (score 7):

I would say "***came across***", as in:

> I was reading the New York Times and *came across* an interesting
>   piece on....

Answer (score 4):

Probably to [glimpse](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Glimpse) may fit:

> v.intr.
> To look briefly; glance: glimpsed at the headlines.

Comment: Thanks, this is nice. Although it sounds a bit like *to look briefly at something one **intended** to look at*, at least to me - but I am no native speaker.

Comment: @miku - it can be used to indicate an intentional look at something, But it is often used for  casual, brief or incomplete views of something. : to catch a glimpse of the sea.

Answer (score 3):

Espy - to catch sight of.

You can use it in several contexts.

I accidently espied a weird word while looking for a word in the dictionary.

I espied a new fact while turning the pages of her notebook.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me a new word. I think it suits the requirements well.